# Accessing NSDocument from NSWindowController subclass?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, document-based

I am creating simple document based app. So far I have implemented NSDocument subclass, which is `Document` and NSWindowController subclass, which is `ToolbarWindowController`. ToolbarWindowController controlls the toolbar, which has sliders to modify user's opened image.

Where I am having issue right now is applying filters (modifying image) on opened image: I can't figure out how to use opened image as source in `ToolbarWindowController`.

F.e. when I open image in `Document` I can set it as `ViewController` imageView, in `makeWindowControllers`:

```
- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
    image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    return YES;
}
- (void)makeWindowControllers {
    NSStoryboard* const storyboard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    NSWindowController* const windowController = [storyboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"Document Window Controller"];
    [[((ViewController *)[windowController contentViewController]) imageView] setImage:image];

    [self addWindowController: windowController];
}
```

Can I somehow access my `ToolbarWindowController` properties/variables and create a `NSImage` property there to modify there opened image? Or can I access `Document` properties to achieve the same thing? Does it even work that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSWindowController` has a `document` property. If everything is hooked up properly, that property will point at the `NSDocument` object that owns the `NSWindowController`.

Comment: SO is no code writing service. What is the problem with accessing a property?

Comment: I believe, I asked question with obvious answer... I can access `document` property, but I don't know how to access it's properties. I am trying to access it as usual `[self.document getProperty]` or `self.document.property` but it does not work, I am really confused with this document based app and apple documentation confuses me even more..

Comment: You'll need a cast to use dot syntax, like `((Document *)self.document).property`. You used a similar cast (to `ViewController *`) in the code you posted. Try logging `self.document`. Is it the correct class?

Comment: It is correct class, casting worked like a charm! Thank you!